# How do I determine where process executable code starts and ends when loaded in memory?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, process

Say I have app TestApp.exe
While TestApp.exe is running I want a separate program to be able to read the executable code that is resident in memory. I'd like to ignore stack and heap and anything else that is tangential.

Put another way, I guess I'm asking how to determine where the memory-side equivalent of the .exe binary data on disk resides. I realize it's not a 1:1 stuffing into memory.

Edit: I think what I'm asking for is shown as **Image** in the following screenshot of vmmap.exe
[image: http://i.imgur.com/bARgC.png]

Edit: I am able to get from memory all memory that is tagged with any protect flag of Execute* (PAGE_EXECUTE, etc) using VirtualQueryEx and ReadProcessMemory. There are a couple issues with that. First, I'm grabbing about 2 megabytes of data for notepad.exe which is a 189 kilobyte file on disk. Everything I'm grabbing has a protect flag of PAGE_EXECUTE. Second, If I run it on a different Win7 64bit machine I get the same data, only split in half and in a different order. I could use some expert guidance. :)

Edit: Also, not sure why I'm at -1 for this question. If I need to clear anything up please let me know.

Comment: What on Earth is the point of reading code from memory when you've got it in a file?

Comment: One valid reason would be to make an app similar to the one in the screenshot? Why does it matter why, though?

Comment: The app you showed makes no attempt to read executable code.

Comment: The app I showed is not what I intend to write. At any rate, are you able to provide assistance?

Comment: The answer is hidden in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724162/windows-nt4-stack-and-heap-address-space). But what you're doing is very strange. Why do you need to mess with another process's memory space like that? Programs that do that may trigger malware detectors.

Comment: For testing purposes I'm writing this as an external tool. Ultimately it will end up in a process that reads its own memory, though. Maybe that helps with an answer?

Comment: It's strange then that you asked a question much harder than the one you actually wanted to ask. It's much easier for a process to access its own memory than it is some other process's memory.

Comment: I'm not opposed to doing it in-process. Shall I submit another question for a self process query?

Comment: If you're only interested in the primary module (and your comments regarding notepad appear to suggest that), you can just call GetModuleHandle on yourself and then extract the information from the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned a ton doing this project. I ended up parsing the PE header and using that information to route me all over. In the end I accomplished what I set out to and I am more knowledgeable as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a DLL to the target process and call `GetModuleHandle` with the name of the executable. That will point to its PE header that has been loaded in the memory. Once you have this information, you can parse the PE header manually and find where `.text` section is located relative to the base address of the image in the memory.

Comment: Injecting a DLL won't be feasible for my application of this. How does your answer change if we shift from reading the memory of a different process to reading one's own memory?

Comment: Due to ASLR, you cannot know where the executable code section will be located in the memory.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, by "you cannot know" do you mean know as in pre-knowledge or know as in determine through some means?

Comment: @RobotCaleb AFAIK, it is impossible to predict where the the code section will be located in the memory(if it would, then that ASLR implementation would be essentially flawed). That being said, the easiest way of finding the base address of a loaded memory would be to call GetModuleHandle within that process.

Answer (score 0):

no need to inject a dll
use native api hooking apis