# Windows NT4 stack and heap address space

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm trying to search for an integer value in the stack and heap memory of Windows NT4. This integer is used by another program.

The problem is I don't know the address range of the stack and heap, is there a way to find the range of this address space?

Previously I've tried searching this integer value in the code space by using EnumProcessModules function of PSAPI (a windows api). From this function, I get the addresses containing the modules of the program which I can then search through to find some variables. This technique works for simple programs like Minesweeper, somehow, it fail to find any useful integer or variables in more complex programs.

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help me with this.

Comment: How do you plan to locate the heap or the stack? Or you are simply attempting to dump the entire memory of a process, by brute force, and search for matches to an arbitrary 4 byte pattern? This question piles an unanswerable question upon unanswerable assumptions.  Why do you assume that a particular value must exist in the representation you think it exists in, inside the memory of some large complex running program that (for all you know) might be running in Java or C# + .net and might not be easily reverse engineered by you?

Comment: For now, I can only think of searching through address 0x00000000 to the base address of that program, lets say 0x01000000. Using this method, there is gonna be a lot matching 4byte pattern that may not be the integer I am looking for.

Looking at the GUI, the program looks like it is written in C or C++, it is a primitive but complex program used to control chip fabrication machines. Furthermore I couldn't contact the vendor for that machine because it is already a discontinued product.

Comment: If I was stuck in your shoes, I'd be investigating scriptable debuggers like `gdb` and reverse-engineering and decompilation tools.

Comment: that is a good idea. thanx Warren